# Open iOS application from url without redirecting to browser

Tags: ios, iphone, url-scheme

I know how to add `URL Schemes` to an iOS application. But from messages the url with custom scheme doesn't detect as link, for solving this issue I used url redirection technique(redirect a valid url to app url from Safari). But how to show my application upon clicking a link without navigating to the browser. How to show open with menu while clicking a specific link from messages.

Comment: I think alot of them use universal links, these are just standard links but the app knows how to handle them, so if the app is installed it opens in that, if not it opens in the web browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps that open immediately without going through Safari first are using [Universal Links](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9). These links don't work everywhere so you still need the URL scheme redirect you've already set up, but supporting both should cover most edge cases.